# Grpc cannot resolve symbol GreeterGrpc

Tags: java, grpc

I am following the link https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/tree/master/examples/src/main/java/io/grpc/examples/helloworld here to try to get grpc working.

[image]

this is the final folder structure.

And my HelloWorldServer.java is the same as https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/io/grpc/examples/helloworld/HelloWorldServer.java, except the package name.

but Intellij tells that it cannot resolve symbol GreeterGrpc.

Could someone help me out of here please?

Answer (score 11):

Notice that `GreeterGrpc.java` is under `generated-sources`,
but IntelliJ doesn't know it's a source file.

I see that `target/generated-sources/protobuf/java` is marked as generated sources root, but `target/generated-sources/protobuf/grpc-java` is not.
Normally IntelliJ picks this up from the configuration in `pom.xml`.
Maybe you don't have something correctly configured there.
You could try to reimport the Maven module by right-click on `pom.xml`,
and select **Maven** and then **Reimport**.
The icon of `grpc-java` should change to blue with a gear,
like `java` at the same directory level.

If that doesn't work,
then you could mark `grpc-java` as a generated source root manually:
right-click on it, select **Mark Directory as** and then **Generated Sources Root**.

Answer (score 5):

The Protobuf plugin assumes Protobuf files (*.proto) are organized in the same way as Java source files, in sourceSets. The Protobuf files of a sourceSet are compiled in a single protoc run, and the generated files are added to the input of the Java compilation run of that sourceSet ().

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs 'build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc'
            srcDirs 'build/generated/source/proto/main/java'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, first of all a problem (in Eclipse) was using single quotes around `$` variables. My working `gradle.build` to compile proto files to Java classes in a custom directory was this:

```
protobuf {
    protoc { artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:${protocVersion}" }
    plugins {
        grpc { artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:${grpcVersion}" }
    }
    generatedFilesBaseDir = "$projectDir/gensrc"
    generateProtoTasks {
        all()*.plugins { grpc {} }
    }
}

// Inform IDEs like IntelliJ IDEA, Eclipse or NetBeans about the generated code.
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs "${protobuf.generatedFilesBaseDir}/main/java"
            srcDirs "${protobuf.generatedFilesBaseDir}/main/grpc"
        }
    }
}
```

Then Eclipse could not tell these were source files. I had to refresh the project:

[image: refresh]

Then add the custom files to the build path

[image: build path]

Answer (score 0):

Just as the [quick-start](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/java/quickstart/) said:
Compile the client and server:

> $ ./gradlew installDist

then the GreeterGrpc.java will be generated in ./build file.